# Is it always true that the inner product is a map from a vector space to a scalar field?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In other words, is the inner product a bilinear functional?

That is for $x,y \in V$ where $V$ is a vector space, is it always true that $\langle . \rangle: V\to \mathbb{F}$. Is it ever possible that the inner product maps back to another vector space?

The reason I asked this is because I am reading a book on functional analysis and I feel they overcomplicated the proof for the Schwartz inequality a bit. For some reason they all start with $0 \leq \| x  - \alpha y\|^2 = \langle x - \alpha y,  x - \alpha y\rangle $.

I found it much easier to prove this starting with the projection.

> $$| \langle u,v \rangle | \leq \| u \| \| v \| \dots(4)$$
>
> **Sketch of Proof**
>
> Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $u$, Then $\|P_Wv\| = \| \dfrac{<v,u>}{<u,u>} u\| = \left | \dfrac{<v,u>}{<u,u>} \right | \| u\| = \dfrac{|<u,v>|}{\| u\|} \leq \| v \| $

Comment: It is bilinear if the field is real.

Comment: But does the inner product always map to a scalar field? Whether real or complex?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: No, an inner product on a complex vector space is *not* bilinear. It is [sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear).

Comment: "Is it ever possible that the inner product maps back to another vector space?" Sure, because a field is a vector space over itself.

Answer (score 1):

It does maps to a field and exceptions are noted if they occur.  There are silly hacks like making it map to $F \oplus F$ but to the elements of type $(f,f)$ with all coordinates equal. To avoid this, you want to assume that the inner product is surjective
onto its range.

That proof of the Schwarz inequality is set up to work in general settings like function spaces.  Geometry may not be available to prove the properties in such an abstract setting and it is desirable to use only bilinearity and positivity.

For complex spaces the Hermitian inner product is the one most commonly used.  The ordinary inner product lacks positivity for vectors with complex components.

Comment: could you provide a counterexample where the projection method may not hold? Thanks

Comment: If you say what the projection method is, I can try.

Comment: I will edit my OP to show the proof